# jQuery widget Inside jQuery ajax tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having some problems with adding a datepicker into a ajax loaded site on a tab widget.
I'll try to explain what I have done so far.

I have first made all my forms and stuff, added a datepicker and made sure everything worked. Then I wanted to create a tab widget wich would load the page with the form into it.
While this does work and all the $_post stuff works too, the jQuery doesn't seem to work.

Are there any know causes to this or could this be a specific problem related to me?

If code is needed to help figure this out I'll edit it later, but for now I want to know if it's even possible.

Please keep in mind that I am relatively new to all this jQuery and AJAX stuff.
Thanks in advance!

--EDIT--

Note: I Include the scripts in the headers of each page.

Page with tabs:

View

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="../tabs/bericht">Bericht</a></li>
    <li><a href="../main/initiative">Initiatief</a></li>
    <li><a href="../main/profile">Interesse</a></li>
</ul>
```

Java

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({collapsible:true, active:false, effect:'ajax'});
});
```

Loaded page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#date').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});

var counter = 1;

$("#addButton").click(function () {

    if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<input type="text" name="requirements' + counter + '" id="requirements' + counter + '" value="" >&nbsp;<input type="text" name="requirementscount' + counter + '" id="requirementscount' + counter + '" value="" size="2"><br>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");


    counter++;
 });

 $("#removeButton").click(function () {
if(counter==1){
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
   }   

counter--;

    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

 });
});
```

(is this enough to make it work?)

Comment: should work fine if you initialize datepicker after ajax data loaded. Show your code.  @Joe... Initializing plugins after ajax and event delegation are different issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used the datepicker function on document ready, but at this time your date element doesn't registered in DOM, so
To make datepicker work properly, you have to call the $('#date').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'}) function after the ajax content get loaded.

For this you have to class Tabs callback method "load"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
load: function( event, ui ) {
    if($('#date').length>0){
                $('#date').datetimepicker({dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'});
    }
}
});
});
```

Comment: This all works. But when I switch to another tab and then switch back the widget stops loading again.

Comment: you can use the if($('#date').length>0) to detect if date element exist in the specific tab content.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready()` is only effective within a main page.

When you load new content with AJAX the  `ready` event has already occurred so your ajax loaded code will fire immediately. This means if your code that is loaded precedes the html it references, it will fire before that html exists.

Several ways you can work around it are:

Place the ajax loaded code after the html it references within the file that is ajax loaded

or

Use the load callback of tabs to run the code for the ajax content

Comment: Thanks a lot!(blablabla comment)